# How to fit an image with respect of ratio in an <ion-col> (ionic3)?

Tags: css, typescript, ionic3

I have to display images on mobile interface. 
The problem is that some photos don't have the same dimensions. I want when the user uploads images they will be displayed the same height and width without being cropped or twisted.

This is the code where they are displayed:

```
<ion-row >
        <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let image of imageURI">
          <a href="#" class="icon pull-right color-red closeBtn fa-stack-2x" (click)="removeImg(image)">
          </a>
          <img src="{{image}}" *ngIf="imageURI" style="z-index: -20"/>
        </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

and this is the output:

[image]

and this is the `css` style :

```
.closeBtn::before {
   content: '\f057';
   z-index: 5;
   position: absolute;
   right: -11px;
   top: -13px;
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.closeBtn {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: You want different aspect ratio pictures to show as same aspect ratio pictures without being cropped or skewed?  (not likely there is an answer to this)

Comment: in this case, is there a way to show the biggest one skewed? :/

Comment: You could set fixed width and height, you could set a fixed height and only change width. Could you share  some more HTML